# A sphere $S^{n}\subseteq \mathbb{R^{n+1}}$ is simply connected for $n\geq 2$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Show that the sphere $S^{n}\subseteq \mathbb{R^{n+1}}$ is simply connected when $n\geq 2$

Hints that I have are following :

$\textbf{Step 1}$
Every curve $\gamma:I \rightarrow S^{n}$ whose image is not the whole sphere (circle ) can be deformed continuously over the sphere (circle) to a single point by a simple geometric construction ! (Think of stereographic projection)

(Infact I have got that first step by considering the stereographic projection.)

So the only curves that make problems are (for $n\geq2$ ) the very pathological $\textbf{surjective}$ curves (so -called Peano curves)!

$\textbf{Step2}$ Use [Continuously deformation (homotopy) of continuous function into an arbitrary close $C^{\infty}$-function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2465875/continuously-deformation-homotopy-of-continuous-function-into-an-arbitrary-clo), applied to the component of a curve $\gamma :I \rightarrow S^{n}$ . The problem is to get a "homotopy" with values again in $S^{n}$. Reduce to step 1

Please help me ,May be its really basic but unfortunately I am not getting , I will be very grateful for it .

Comment: Please include only relevant information to your problem in the body of the post. In particular, avoid asking for help without being specific as to the question you have in mind, and avoid linking to other questions you have made that are not related to your post.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to do this :

- You can find the null-homotopy explicitly. You can 'roll up' the closed curve to the north pole along great circles. (You may think this for $n=2$ case first.)
- Use Seifert Van Kampen theorem to compute $\pi_{1}(S^{n}) = 0$ by consider $S^{n}$ as union of two disks $D^{n}$ with intersection homotopic to $S^{n-1}$.
- $S^{n}$ is homeomorphic to the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to show that the sphere $S^n$ is simply connected when $n\geq2$ is to observe that it is isomorphic to the closed ball $D_n=\{x\in{\Bbb R}^n\,\mid\,|x|\leq1\}$ with the boundary identified to one single point, and the boundary is itself connected.

When $n=1$ the identification is still true, but in that case the boundary of the segment $[-1,1]$ is not connected.

Comment: ,Dear Sir Thanks for giving me hint,I am getting somehow but not completely infact . I will be grateful if you can suggest me some book or reading stuff to understand

Answer (score 0):

We will show that if $k>n$, then $\pi_n(S^k)$ is trivial. This reduces to your question if we put $n=1$.

$S^i$ has an obvious CW-strucute given by one $0$-cell and one $i$-cell. Now if we are given any continuous map $f:S^n \to S^k$ where $n < k$, then by the cellular approximation theorem , $f$ is homotopic to a map whose image is contained in the $n$-skeleton of $S^k$. But the $n$-skeleton of $S^k$ consists only of that single $0$-cell, i.e. a single point. Thus $f$ is homotopic to a constant map and therefore $\pi_n(S^k)$ is the trivial group.

Comment: Can you suggest me some book or reading material to understand it in a detail.

Comment: @muhammadmohsin You should be able to find this in most texts on algebraic topology. There is for example [the book by Hatcher](https://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf) which is available for free online.